# Использование escape-последовательностей при форматировании таблицы в Golang

Tags: golang, ascii

Я хочу выделить цветом (escape-последовательностями) определенные значения в таблице, отформатированной при помощи встроенной библиотеки "text/tabwriter". Однако после применения последовательности таблица съезжает.
Как можно правильно выделять цветом элементы таблицы? Возможно, существуют библиотеки, реализующие эту функцию более эффективно?
Ниже представлен код и скриншот работы примера такой таблицы:

```
func main() {
    cReset := "\033[0m"
    cRed := "\033[31m"
    my_table := tabwriter.NewWriter(os.Stdout, 0, 0, 1, ' ', tabwriter.AlignRight|tabwriter.Debug)
    fmt.Fprintln(my_table, "Col_1[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]\tCol_2\tCol_3")
    fmt.Fprintln(my_table, "testtesttesttesttest\ttest\ttest")
    my_cell := fmt.Sprint(cRed + "Red_test" + cReset)
    fmt.Fprintf(my_table, "%s\ttest\ttest\n", my_cell)
    fmt.Fprintln(my_table, "testtesttesttesttest\ttest\ttest")
    my_table.Flush()
}
```

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35398497/